# How to design a REST resource to find objects from different resources?

Tags: rest, api-design

I have resources:

```
/countries/
/countries/{countryName}/
/countries/{countryName}/cities/
/countries/{countryName}/cities/{cityName}
```

I want to add the ability to the REST API to get the cities of any country with a specific name (or meeting other criteria, such as population, area, etc). How could I do that (what resource and method should I make)?

Comment: Why not use a `/cities/{cityName}` endpoint for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I think it is a good idea. How about a method, if I want to use many parameters for searching (population, square, etc.). Should I use HTTP GET with query params or use the custom method `search` with HTTP POST?

Comment: It's up to you to decide that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say make a resource

```
/cities
```

And make it POST and pass your query params as JSON doc